# WordPress. Проблемы с выводом произвольных категорий произвольных типов записей не могу вывести категории по ID записи

Tags: php, wordpress

Помогите решить вопрос с категориями.
мне нужно получать категорию по id произвольного типа поста(товара)
я создал произвольную таксономию (Категория товара) для товаров и создал произвольный тип записей(Товары).

пытаюсь в шаблоне получить категорию с помощью функции

```
$category = get_the_category(166); 
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($category);
echo '</pre>';
```

**но выводит пустой массив. это когда я смотрю произвольную категорию.
А когда я смотрю тип записи wordpress 
т.е его базовый тип где новости добавляют. то он выводит ее категорию 
т.е. массив не пустой и там есть категория записи.
А мне нужна моя категория моего типа записи. а он не находит. как быть?**

регистрация произвольной категории

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_taxonomy' );
function create_taxonomy(){
    // список параметров: http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_taxonomy_labels
    register_taxonomy('category_goods', array('goods_post_type'), array(
        'label'                 => 'Категория товара', // определяется параметром $labels->name
        'labels'                => array(
            'name'              => 'Категория',
            'singular_name'     => 'Категория товара',
            'search_items'      => 'Поиск категорий товара',
            'all_items'         => 'Все категории товаров',
            'view_item '        => 'Показать категорию товара',
            'parent_item'       => 'Родительская',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Родительская',
            'edit_item'         => 'Редактировать категорию товара',
            'update_item'       => 'Обновить категорию товара',
            'add_new_item'      => 'Добавить новую категорию товара',
            'new_item_name'     => 'Новое имя Категории товара',
            'menu_name'         => 'Категории товаров',
        ),
        'description'           => '', // описание таксономии
        'public'                => true,
        'publicly_queryable'    => null, // равен аргументу public
        'show_in_nav_menus'     => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_ui'               => true, // равен аргументу public
        'show_in_menu'          => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        'show_tagcloud'         => true, // равен аргументу show_ui
        'show_in_rest'          => null, // добавить в REST API
        'slug'                  => 'goods',
        'rest_base'             => null, // $taxonomy
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        //'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'rewrite'               => true,
        'query_var'             => $goods_taxonomy, // название параметра запроса
        'capabilities'          => array(),
        'meta_box_cb'           => null, // callback функция. Отвечает за html код метабокса (с версии 3.8): post_categories_meta_box или post_tags_meta_box. Если указать false, то метабокс будет отключен вообще
        'show_admin_column'     => false, // Позволить или нет авто-создание колонки таксономии в таблице ассоциированного типа записи. (с версии 3.5)
        '_builtin'              => false,
        'show_in_quick_edit'    => null, // по умолчанию значение show_ui
    ) );
}

add_action('init','good_cat_for_goods');
function good_cat_for_goods(){
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category_goods','good_cat_for_goods');
}
```

вот регистрация произвольных типов записей

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );
function register_post_types(){
    register_post_type('goods_post_type', array(
        'label'  => null,
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => 'Товары', // основное название для типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'Товар', // название для одной записи этого типа
            'add_new'            => 'Добавить товар', // для добавления новой записи
            'add_new_item'       => 'Добавление товара', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
            'edit_item'          => 'Редактирование товара', // для редактирования типа записи
            'new_item'           => 'Новый товар', // текст новой записи
            'view_item'          => 'Смотреть товар', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
            'search_items'       => 'Искать товар', // для поиска по этим типам записи
            'not_found'          => 'Не найдено', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Не найдено в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
            'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
            'menu_name'          => 'Товары', // название меню
        ),
        'description'         => '',
        'public'              => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true, // зависит от public
        'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
        'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
        'show_in_menu'        => null, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => null, // по умолчанию значение show_in_menu
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
        'show_in_rest'        => null, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
        'rest_base'           => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
        'menu_position'       => 4,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-feedback', 
        //'capability_type'   => 'post',
        //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
        //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'supports'            => array('title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','comments'), // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
        'taxonomies'          => array('category_goods'),
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'query_var'           => true,
    ) );
}
```

**я создал категории. я создал товары. связал их(в админке).
но возвращает пустой массив где бывают категории.
SOS :c
вот дебаг массива товаров.
там нет категории. как ее достать ??**

может категории как то в ядре WP не соединились с товарами.такое возможно ?
Помогите мне гуры WP :))
говорите что нужно отправить если не понятно.))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы зарегистрировали таксономию, и поэтому искать следует элементы этой таксономии. Такие элементы называются «**terms**» («термины»), и для них есть [специальная функция](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_terms):

```
get_the_terms( $id, $taxonomy );
```

Оба аргумента обязательны:

- `$id` (число/WP_Post) — ID или объект записи, термины (элементы таксономии) которой нужно получить.
- `$taxonomy` (строка) — Название таксономии, термины которой нужно получить.

Название «**category**» используется для встроенной таксономии, относящийся к записям. Если посмотреть код функции `get_the_category()`, то её первая строчка как раз вызывает `get_the_terms()`:

```
$categories = get_the_terms( $id, "category" );
```

Получается, с заказчиком говорим по-человечески («категории», «рубрики»), а для себя переводим всё на язык Вордпресса — «элементы таксономий», «типы записей» и т. п.

Comment: Спасибо)) +15xp